# Embed .Net dll into Microsoft Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, dll

1) Is it possible to embed a .net dll into a Microsoft Access database? Ideally I want the dll actually embedded into the access database, so it can't go missing. I need to access a few APIs from within my access database.

2) If it is possible, what are the limitations? I'm assuming the access database would have to be used on a machine that had .net installed. Are there any other issues that I should consider?

Comment: That seems to be an exceptionally bad solution to whatever problem you have. Why don't you ask about your actual problem instead?

Comment: You can store a word, or .exe or .dll inside of Access. So on the Access startup you could certainly check for the existence of the .dlls, and if not found then pull them out of say a local table in Access and place the .dlls in the same dir as your application.  However as noted until such time you pull the .net (COM) files out, they cannot be used by Access. And in most cases you would also have to register such COM objects before they can be used - this means users will need enough rights to register COM objects unless the side by side .net approach can be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This actually seems to be 2 slightly different questions than the ones asked, if I'm reading it correctly: (1) Can you embed a binary in an JET/ACE database? and (2) Can you call methods from a .NET DLL from MS-Access?

1. Yes, you can embed a binary file in an JET/ACE database.  My preferred way of doing this is by reading the file as binary and encoding as base64 in a Memo field.

First, you need to read in the binary file into a byte array.  This can be done using `Open`, or by using an `ADODB.Stream` object.  Then, you encode the byte array as a Base64 string, and finally, you write that string to a table.  To export the binary, you do the opposite.

Here are functions to convert a byte array to Base 64 ([Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20060527094535/http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-encode-decode-base64-vb6.asp)):

```
'Requires reference to Microsoft XML v3.0
Private Function EncodeBase64(ByRef arrData() As Byte) As String

    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    ' help from MSXML
    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    ' byte array to base64
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text

    ' thanks, bye
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

End Function

Private Function DecodeBase64(ByVal strData As String) As Byte()

    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    ' help from MSXML
    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.Text = strData
    DecodeBase64 = objNode.nodeTypedValue

    ' thanks, bye
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

End Function
```

And, here are examples of how to use those Base64 functions to import and export a binary file into a Memo field using an `ADODB.Stream` object:

```
Function ImportBinary()
    'Requires a reference to ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 or higher
    Dim InputStream As ADODB.stream
    Dim FileBytes() As Byte

    Set InputStream = New ADODB.stream
    InputStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    InputStream.Open
    InputStream.LoadFromFile ("A:\Binary\File\To\Import.dll")
    FileBytes = InputStream.Read()

    With CurrentDb().TableDefs("TableWithMemoField").OpenRecordset
        .AddNew
        !MemoField.Value = EncodeBase64(FileBytes)
        .Update
        .Close
    End With

    InputStream.Close
End Function

Function ExportBinary()
    Dim OutputStream As ADODB.stream

    Set OutputStream = New ADODB.stream
    OutputStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    OutputStream.Open

    With CurrentDb().TableDefs("TableWithMemoField").OpenRecordset
        OutputStream.Write DecodeBase64(!MemoField.Value)
        .Close
    End With

    OutputStream.SaveToFile "A:\Binary\File\To\Export.dll"

    OutputStream.Close
End Function
```

Alternatively, you could also embed the file(s) into OLE fields, or, recent versions of Access also have an "Attachment" field. I believe it is possible to use this.

2. Yes, it's possible to call methods from a .NET DLL - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13333819/864414).  What you are essentially doing is hosting the .NET runtime in Access.

The limitation is that you can only host the .NET 2.0 or 3.5 runtime -- despite the fact that the linked page says you can use 4.0.  As far as I know, there is no easy way to host the .NET 4.0+ runtime in VBA.  If you try to call a 4.0+ DLL, you will get an error to the effect of "the assembly is newer than the runtime".

Yes, you'd also need to use it on a machine that had the 2.0 and/or 3.5 runtimes installed on it.

Also, it won't load a DLL directly from a network share.  This is a limitation of the .NET framework which it is possible to overcome ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13586128/864414)), but I'm not sure if that can be done when hosting the DLL in Access.

In order to use the "embedded" DLL, you need to export it from the database before you use it; a good place would be the user's temp folder.

**EDIT:** Regarding point (2)-- I had previously written that you do not need to expose your C# class as COM, however, after testing this I realized this was incorrect. You do need to declare your class with a `[COMVisible(true)]` attribute (or implement an IDispatch interface) in order for VBA to correctly instantiate your class-- otherwise `CreateInstanceFrom` will return Nothing.

Comment: Access should consume .net 4.5 just fine. If you simply create a vb.net class object, and tick the register for COM interop, then the class will appear in the windows “standard” list of references from the VBA editor (tools->references). I used .net 4.5 it this works fine with Access. About the only suggestion is to limit (force) the .net application to run/compile as x86 (forced 32 bit). And not only would a export of the .dll be required, but also a regasm to register and expose the .net as a standard COM object. You cannot create standard windows .dll with .net – only COM objects.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I think you are talking about something slightly different. Using the COM method, you are absolutely right - the higher .NET framework can be used.  But -- as you have said, it requires registration unless actual SxS reg can be used.  The linked-to answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903220/side-by-side-com-interop-with-c-sharp-and-vba/13333819#13333819) actually _hosts_ the .NET framework in Access, which is a little different-- it doesn't require reg.  At the time I wrote that answer, however, I was confusing my concepts a bit, thinking I was using SxS.

Comment: Actually as far as I can tell, that linked answer simply allows you to consume a .net COM object without having to register it. So it is no “more” or “less” hosting the app inside of Access as opposed to allowing one to use a normal .net COM object. However it certainly is a “big” bonus not having to register the .net object. I am thus going to look into this, since often users don’t have rights to register .com objects (they require registry changes). So still a “great” point on your part and if I can get this working I will adopt this for my Access applications that use .net objects.